# Understanding cin behaviour in C++

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ and came to this problem. Could someone provide me with explanation why my solution doesn't work ? Here's my code and the problem:

```
struct Pizza {
    char company[30];
    double size;
    int weight;
};

int main() {
    Pizza *test = new Pizza;

    cout << "Enter size: ";

    //from Internet, works
    (cin >> test->size).get();

    //my idea, doesnt work, why ?
    cin >> test->size;

    cout << "Enter company: ";
    cin.get(test->company, 30);
    cout << "Enter weight: ";
    cin >> test->weight;
    cout << "Company: " << test->company<< " \nSize: "
        << test->size << " \nWeight: " << test->weight << endl;
    delete test;
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the point in using a pointer and new/delete, instead of a regular local variable? That's the wrong way to learn C++.  Your question has nothing to do with *dynamism*

Comment: If you think it has something to do with "dynamic structs", why not try without them and see if the problem goes away?

Comment: It was excercise from a book about C++. Now I see that the problem wasn't with struct itself, but with my lack of knowledge about cin object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cin >> test->size;` works perfectly :)

The reason why you *think* that is because there would still be a new line `\n` in the stream. Afterwards, when you `cin.get(test->company, 30);`, it reads the stream, and returns immediately, because it read the new line.

But when you call `std::cin.get()`, it reads one character, the new line, and discards it from the stream, so the stream is empty, and you can enter the company name.

You could also call it afterwards:

```
cin >> test.size();
cin.get();
```